# PDF reader that supports form editing and doesn't ask me to "save as"

Tags: pdf

I use Evince now for PDF forms. However, each time I hit save it's only "save copy" or "save as".

Ideally I would like to save and just have it save without the extra prompts and questions about overwriting etc.

Suggestions?